# SQL Replication cannot access file

Tags: sql, merge-replication

When setting up a subscriber it fails on the first sync with the message

```
The process could not read file <file-name> due to OS error 2
```

I have tried setting the security rights for the directory to full control for the user credential that runs the replication, but still not success.